# python package not packaging files under a subdirectory

Tags: python, python-3.6

Here is my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

import versioneer

REQUIRES = [
    "requests",
    "subprocess32",
    "systemd"
]

CLASSIFIERS = [
    ...
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    "Programming Language :: Python",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6"
]

setup(
    author="IBM",
    cmdclass=versioneer.get_cmdclass(),
    description="A collections of utilities",
    entry_points={},
    install_requires=REQUIRES,
    keywords=["management", "segment_sqls"],
    license="XXX",
    long_description="""Utilities for instance management and house keeping""",
    packages=find_packages(),
    tests_require=["pytest"],
    url="https://github.ibm.com/myrepo/management",
    name="management",
    version=versioneer.get_version(),
    classifiers=CLASSIFIERS
)
```

I am trying to run `python3 setup.py sdist upload -r local` to package and upload to my artifactory.The package's tar.gz is uploaded to artifactory with all files except the ones under segment_sqls. Here is my directory structure. **init**.py under segment_sqls is packaged but not the actual sql files. Is there any additional param that needs to be specified in setup.py to include all files?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `package_data` allows you to include non-python files to your package.  https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data

Comment: I tried adding `include dashdb_segment/segment_sqls/*.sql` in MANIFEST.in . Now my package has all the required sqls but when I install the package I dont see the segment_sqls directory at all. I removed __init_._py under segment_sqls directory as its not really a python package.

Comment: ok I added `include_package_data=True,` in setup and installation works fine now. Thank you.